# PHP Web Service : Load data from database on scrolling

Tags: php, sql, web-services, mysqli

I am making a web service in PHP. 
I want to load several data, let say **10** records.

So when it appears in the mobile app, then first **10** records should be displayed, then if user scroll down then again **10** records should be displayed.

```php
<?php

$limit = 10; // limit of 10 records

$userQuery="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `agenda` WHERE agenda_event_id=$event_id 
                     LIMIT $limit ) AS R1
                     INNER JOIN `bookmeeting` ON R1.agenda_id=bookmeeting.event_id";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$userQuery);

$number=mysqli_num_rows($result);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $getdata['data'][] = $row;
}
```

Above is my code.

Where am I lacking?

Comment: use lazy load plugin or ajax

Comment: you need to call web service after each 10 records and app developer will pass  limit.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code, You need to set $page value for each request.

```
//Need to set this variable when you send request to get next 10 records, default value would be 1
$page=1;
$offset = 10;
$limit = ($page - 1) * 10;

$userQuery="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `agenda` WHERE agenda_event_id= $event_id LIMIT $limit ) AS R1 INNER JOIN `bookmeeting` ON R1.agenda_id=bookmeeting.event_id";

if($page > 0)
    $userQuery .= " limit $limit, $offset";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$userQuery);

    $number=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $getdata['data'][] = $row;
    }
```